# Какую базу данных выбрать?

Tags: база-данных, sql

Мне предстоит писать проект с веб интерфейсом для одной фирмы. Проект представляет из себя прогамму учета склада а так же продаж, т.е. счета, клиенты, проданные товары, оставшиеся на складе. Естественно нельзя чтобы потерялось из за глюка в базе. Вот например в mysql часто бывает что в таблицах возникают ошибки и их приходится исправлять.
Ошибки вызваны например отказами базы и т.д. (мне даже кажется надежней хранить информацию по файлам). После исправления все естественно работает, но допустим 2 строки из базы потеряны, а мне такого не нужно. Нужна именно надежная база, ну и шустрая. В то же время не тяжелая.

Какая СУБД наиболее надежная?

Comment: > Вот например в mysql часто бывает что в таблицах возникают ошибки и их приходится исправлять

думаю, это ошибки вызваны либо ошибками программиста, либо ошибками железа. Либо, целенаправленным вредительством со стороны человека. А от этого не защищена ни одна база данных.

В современных базах данных если просто так могут потеряться пару строк - то это серьезный баг и такое дело обычно быстро исправляют.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне нравится Postgresql. После этой СУБД в сторону mysql смотреть не хочется.

Answer (score 9):

Забавная ситуация - MySQL - продукт, разрабатываемый аж 1995 года (может, даже чуть раньше). Разрабатывается высококвалифицированными профессионалами, которым вы, [[[[@fffffffggggggggg](/users/14306/fffffffggggggggg)](/users/14306/fffffffggggggggg)](/users/14306/fffffffggggggggg)](/users/14306/fffffffggggggggg), при всём уважении, в подмётки не годитесь (и я  тоже не гожусь), людьми из небезызвестной компании Oracle. И тут на сцену выходит уважаемый [[[[@fffffffggggggggg](/users/14306/fffffffggggggggg)](/users/14306/fffffffggggggggg)](/users/14306/fffffffggggggggg)](/users/14306/fffffffggggggggg) с супер-проектом "прогамма учета склада а так же продаж" и высококомпетентно и с полной ответственностью заявляет, что "вот например в mysql часто бывает что в таблицах возникают ошибки и их приходится исправлять". В этот момент небеса рушатся на землю, Oracle увольняет всех своих разработчиков СУБД (в том числе и СУБД Oracle - на всякий случай), объявляет себя банкротом, а Ларри Эллисон уходит в монастырь, подальше от этого позора.

Впрочем, пока что этих апокалиптических событий не случилось, а потому вывод такой - пользуйтесь MySQL, я вас уверяю, ее возможностей и надежности вашему складу со всеми его продажами хватит за глаза.

Comment: http://habrahabr.ru/post/148102/ всегда можно свалить на кого-нить вину и "в таблицах возникают ошибки и их приходится исправлять".

Comment: да, Сбер - это шарашка еще та. Из крупных ему подстать разве что РЖД и Почта России. Для их сотрудников, думаю, в аду уже заготовлено по отдельному котлу